# How can I tell if an active directory group is a security or distribution group?

Tags: security, active-directory

I need to check if an active directory group is a security or distribution group. As somebody who doesn't know much about active directory - how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click <kbd>Start</kbd>, then `Administrative Tools`, then select `Active Directory Users and Computers`.

Click `Continue` when the User Account Control dialog box appears.

If you know where the group is in AD, find and select it.  Otherwise, select the root of the domain and select `Find` and enter the (partial) name of the group and click `Find Now`.

Right click the group and select `Properties`.

In the properties dialog, you will see a `Group type` box and either Security or Distribution will be selected.

Comment: In case ADUC is not available for you or use some kind if script or 3rd party tool, here's a good description of the values: 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2004/12/21/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-group-is-a-security-group-or-a-distribution-group/

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the Active Directory Groups and Computers and find the group by browsing to the Organizational Unit that it belongs to, you can view the group type column on the right hand side of the window.

If you are searching for the group, you can look at the group properties and there should be a radio button section on the right hand side titled "Group Type" that will have either Distribution or Security selected.

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm answering a ten-year-old question, but if you want to do this in PowerShell, you can do it with Get-ADGroup (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroup), and look at the GroupCategory property.